# How to log different classes into different files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Let's say I have different classes defined like this

```
class PS1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_sth(self):
        logging.info('PS1 do sth')

class PS2:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_sth(self):
        logging.info('PS2 do sth')
```

How can I make PS1 log into PS1.log and PS2 log into PS2.log? I know I can set up loggers and file handlers and do something likes **ps1_logger.info** instead of **logging.info**. However, my current code base already has hundreds of **logging.info**, do I have to change them all?

Comment: I'm curious what's the reason for this. Perhaps there is a better/easier way to do what you want. For example, you could include the class name in the logging info, then separate the log file later (or simply grep on the class name).

Comment: Let's say some class write more logs more frequently, some other class write less logs and less frequently. If i just include class name in the log info and write everything in the same file, my concern is log rotation might be an issue. e.g. I might end up with a log file where 90% contents from one class and only 10% from other classes.

Comment: In a way, that makes sense though: the log file is for the *program*, not an individual class. If that program uses a class 90% of the time, then that's (also) clear from the log file. You already have the class name in the logging output (at least in the example), so it's easy to filter the file by class.

Comment: Also, worrying about log rotation is moot: if you separate them out, you still end up with one file rolling over often. The amount of lines and disk spaces remains the same. And you do end up with more files when using separate loggers. But, all that said, I'm afraid I don't have an actual solution for what you want (other than what you already know).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to clarify a bit, it's not really "that program uses a class 90% of the time", it's just some specific class has more logging lines than the other. ( it's not more hardworking, it's just more talkative ). I want to separate the log files by class ( instances of these classes are my workers, each class instance is responsible for a different task, and I run these workers in asyncio ).

Comment: let's say i have 10 classes, if i write to 10 log files ( one for each class ) and set log rotation size limit to 500MB, i can i have 500MB information about each class. If i combine them in the same file and set size limit to 5000MB ( same disk space as the 10*500MB), since one class is more talkative than the rest, i will not have enough information about some classes.

Answer (score 3):

When you call logging methods on the module level you are creating logs directly at the root logger, so you no longer can separate them by logger. The only chance left is to separate your logs by Handler with a filter. Since you don't want to update your logging calls to add any information about where the call happens you have to inspect the stack to find the calling class. The code below does this, but I highly recommend not using this solution in production and refactor your code to not send everything to the root logger. Look into logging adapters and/or the extra keyword argument for an alternative solution that modifies the logging calls.

```py
import logging
import inspect


root = logging.getLogger()

ps1_handler = logging.FileHandler('ps1.log')
ps2_handler = logging.FileHandler('ps2.log')

def make_class_filter(class_name):
    def filter(record):
        for fi in inspect.stack():
            if 'self' in fi[0].f_locals and class_name in str(fi[0].f_locals['self']):
                return True 
        return False
    return filter

ps1_handler.addFilter(make_class_filter('PS1'))
ps2_handler.addFilter(make_class_filter('PS2'))

root.addHandler(ps1_handler)
root.addHandler(ps2_handler)

class PS1:
    def do_sth(self):
        logging.warning('PS1 do sth')

class PS2:
    def do_sth(self):
        logging.warning('PS2 do sth')


PS1().do_sth()
PS2().do_sth()
```

Comment: This indeed works, thank you @blues . Your are right, this is now the clean way/right way to handle logging, I'll look into refactoring the code.